# Why does preload fonts block rendering?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

When I write the following code, the rendering is before the script is executed，However, preloaded fonts are added. rendering is performed after the script is executed. Why？

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <!-- <link rel="preload" href="http://localhost:3000/index.woff" crossorigin as="font"> --> // This causes rendering to lag
        <style>
            .demo {
                width: 50px;
                height: 50px;
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="demo"></div>
        <script src="./index.js"> </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Link types: preload**

The preload value of the  element's rel attribute lets you declare fetch requests in the HTML's , specifying resources that your page will need very soon, which you want to start loading early in the page lifecycle, before browsers' main rendering machinery kicks in. This ensures they are available earlier and are less likely to block the page's render, improving performance.

The basics
You most commonly use  to load a CSS file to style your page with:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">`

Copy to Clipboard
Here however, we will use a rel value of preload, which turns  into a preloader for any resource we want. You will also need to specify:

The path to the resource in the href attribute.
The type of resource in the as attribute.
A simple example might look like this (see our JS and CSS example source, and also live):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/preload